# Puppeteer Select Query - How to select this query in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, css-selectors, puppeteer

How can I select this (html anchor element to click and navigate to **Tutorial** page) query using puppeteer ? [image]

I was doing this and it is not working

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = process.argv[2];
if (!url) {
    throw "Please provide URL as a first argument";
}
async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        slowMo: 10,
        args: ['--start-maximzed', '--disable-notifications']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    await page.waitForSelector(".python-navigation .navigation.menu .tier-1.element-3  a", {
        visible: true
    });
    await page.click(".python-navigation .navigation.menu .tier-1.element-3  a");

    await page.waitForSelector(".documentation-banner .download-buttons ", {
        visible: true
    });
    const elem =  await page.$$('.documentation-banner .download-buttons a');
    await elem[0].click();


    await page.waitForSelector(".contentstable", {
        visible: true
    });
    elem =  await page.$$('.contentstable')[0].$$('tbody')[0].$$('tr')[0].$$('td')[0].$$('p')[1];
    await elem.click();


    await page.pdf({path: 'pdfGenerated.pdf',format:"A4"});

    console.log("Success");
    browser.close();
}
run();
```

What should I write instead of this line `elem =  await page.$$('.contentstable')[0].$$('tbody')[0].$$('tr')[0].$$('td')[0].$$('p')[1];`  ?

Comment: try this: `elem =  await page.$$('.contentstable tbody tr td p')[1];`

Comment: It didn't work. It is not clicking and navigating to Tutorial page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for click on an element you can use this code:

```js
await page.click(".contentstable tbody tr td p:nth-child(2) a");
```